# C check reservable RAM with calloc

Tags: c, windows, x86, 64-bit

I wrote a function to see how much memory can allocate with calloc.

Compiled with mingw32 (32bit) the Application prints 1645943600 Bytes (1569Mb).

Compiled with mingw64 (64bit) the Application prints 21408144400 Bytes (19Gb) on a virtul box (Win10 64Bit) machine with 8Gb RAM.

Compiled with mingw64 (64bit) the Application prints 101040000400 Bytes (94Gb) on a Host (Win10 64Bit) System with 64Gb RAM.

The one on 32bit seems ok but the others on 64bit was wrong. Is my code wrong? I call the function with parameter `sizeof(char)`.

```
uint64_t erz_get_max_memory(const uint64_t size, const uint8_t enable_output)
{
    const char LOCAL_FUNCTION_NAME[] = "LOC:GMM";
    char *aramam = { 0 };
    uint64_t realloc_cnt = 0;
    uint64_t realloc_cnt_backup = 0;
    uint16_t filler = 10000;
    
    while(1)
    {
        aramam = (char *)calloc((realloc_cnt), (size));
        if(aramam == NULL)
        {
            if(filler == 1)
            {
                realloc_cnt -= 1;
                if(enable_output) erz_output(green, LOCAL_FUNCTION_NAME, "Possible Storage on this instance: [%llu] bytes -> [%llu] Elements\r\n", realloc_cnt * size, realloc_cnt);
                break;
            }
            realloc_cnt = realloc_cnt_backup;
            filler = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            free(aramam);
            realloc_cnt_backup = realloc_cnt;
            realloc_cnt += filler;
        }
    }
    if(aramam == NULL) free(aramam);
    return realloc_cnt;
}
```

Comment: Is it possibly reporting the amount of available virtual memory?

Comment: `calloc((0), (size));` is not well-defined behavior.

Comment: Your method is imperfect, since it can lead to fragmentation, it reports the *virtual* memory not physical RAM, and it's prone to race conditions. No two runs would likely report the exact same number.

Comment: This will also break for sure:  `if(aramam == NULL) free(aramam);`

Comment: @karttu Actually it is guaranteed to do absolutely nothing. It will not break anything, it is just senseless.

Comment: `if(aramam == NULL) free(aramam);` -> `if(aramam != NULL) free(aramam);` or better just `free(aramam);`. `free(NULL)` is well defined and it does nolthing.

Comment: @Lundin Sorry, I mean that the line is supposed to be `!= NULL` and that breaks the purpose of the function since now the tested memory is left allocated - which all of you knew.

Comment: You was right. There must be !=

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude whats the correct way to calculate the memory which the app can maximal allocate?

Comment: In Windows you can use GlobalMemoryStatusEx API to get available physical memory. However, it does not guarantee that you can allocate at this maximum size.

Comment: While the duplicate is tagged C++, the solution in the highest voted answer is plain C. And there's still no guarantee that two runs will report the exact same number for available memory.

Comment: @Erz _"There must be !"_ well yes, but just `free(aramam)` is even better because `free(NULL)` is well defined and it does nothing.

Comment: @Erz - The returned value *is* the amount of memory you could allocate. The OS can swap some less used parts of you app to disk, and reuse that part of RAM for more allocations. Getting 50% extra space is not at all uncommon. (Except on a 32-bit system, where the 32 bits is the limitation).

Comment: @BoP: On Linux, a good `calloc` doesn't touch the memory it gets from the OS, so even in 64-bit you'd just be testing the amount of virtual address-space. Since Linux allows overcommit of allocations beyond what it has RAM + swap space to back if actually touched, unless you change the normal overcommit limits.  (Or the bookkeeping overhead of multiple allocations if you were doing it that way instead of freeing and making one huge allocation).  But yeah, on the OP's system, it might well actually be dirtying that memory.  Zeroed pages are ideal for compression into swap or other RAM...